# Open excel file to run macro from relative file path in python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am running a code as below in python to open an excel and run a macro. Basically my python script is sitting in

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation
```

and my excel VBA file (Automation.xlsb) is sitting in

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation\Powerpoint
```

I am running this code

```
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'));

filename = os.path.join(fileDir, '../Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb')
filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(filename))
print(filename);

if os.path.exists("Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl

print("Powerpoint generated");
```

but i am getting error

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find C:\\Users\\adrlee\\Desktop\\Python files\\Powerpoint\\Automation.xlsb. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: did you try running code by giving full path manually, just to check it its working?

Comment: it only worked when I did a forward slash of the absolute path. However, this cant be as this file maybe deployed onto other's computer. Hence I was looking at the relative path

Comment: hi @YowE3K can i ask what do u mean state full path in open statement?   isnt the issue here that i cant pass the excel file into the workbooks.open ()?

Comment: If your current directory is `C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation` and the Excel file is `C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation\Powerpoint\Automation.xlsb` wouldn't you want `'./Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb'` instead of `'../Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb'`?

Comment: Sorry about my earlier (deleted) comment - I thought you were passing the relative path to the `Open`, but you are actually passing the absolute path.  I think you just need to specify the path relative to the current path instead of to the current path's parent - i.e. `.` instead of `..`

Comment: @AdrianLeeXinhan - well, obvio the way you're giving the path won't work bcoz its just does not understand `Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb` directly. So it will work if you either know the abs path or relative path to the project dir using `./path-to-the-file`.
@YowE3K - you sound correct

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments and hints guys! I managed to finally get it right:

```
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'));

filename = os.path.join(fileDir, './Powerpoint/Funnel Automation.xlsb')
print(filename);


xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = filename)
del xl

print("Powerpoint generated");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `fileDir` contains

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation\
```

then joining **`..\Powerpoint\Automation.xlsb`** to it will give

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation\..\Powerpoint\Automation.xlsb
```

which is equivalent to

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Powerpoint\Automation.xlsb
```

because `..` is equivalent to the parent directory, and the parent directory of  `...\Python files\Automation` is `...\Python files`.

---

Your question states that the Excel file is actually

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Automation\Powerpoint\Automation.xlsb
```

so you should really be joining  **`.\Powerpoint\Automation.xlsb`** to the `fileDir` variable.  (While `..` refers to the parent directory, `.` refers to the existing directory.)

i.e. use:

```
filename = os.path.join(fileDir, './Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb')
```

Comment: hihi , 

I edited my code such that fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'));

filename = os.path.join(fileDir, './Powerpoint/Automation.xlsb')
filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(filename))
print(filename);


xl=win32.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = filename)
del xl


but im still getting the same error:

 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find C:\\Users\\adrlee\\Desktop\\Python files\\ Automation\\Powerpoint\\Automation.xlsb.